# Law for passport renewel of a us citizen minor in india

Tags: united-states, india, minor, citizenship, dual-citizenship

My sister's daughter is a minor and us citizen by birth. My sister and her husband are separated and her husband has filed a case for divorce and child custody against my sister in Indian family court.

Currently the custody of a child is with my sister. Her daughter's passport is up for renewal in three months and her husband is not giving his signature for concern.

They applied in court for the order. The court is asking for any section or provision under which she can get the order.
 She needs to present any provision or section in front of judge to get the order
 Can u suggest me any section or provision that she can present  any provision in front of judge to get the confirmarion for renewel of a minor

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. "They applied in court for the order." What order? "The court is asking for any section or provision under which she can get the order." That sounds like the court saying why should they give you this "order". That sounds like you told the judge you are entitled to some "order", and the judge is saying, says who?

Comment: You cannot compel someone to sign. Just because they consented in the past does not mean they have to consent now. The only way to get a passport without the other parent's consent would be if the court granted sole custody to one parent, or the court gave permission for one parent to travel abroad with the child. If they're still in the middle of a divorce or child custody dispute, that means your sister doesn't have sole custody yet, and the court is likely not going to allow one parent to take a child whose custody is in dispute outside the country.